# Calculate percentage of poll chart

Tags: php, percentage

I have a simple poll with multiple answers. I use in the result the percentage of the answer as width of my chart.

For example:

- Answer 1 20%
- Answer 2 39%
- Answer 3 5%
- Answer 4 11%

etc..

(the percentage above is the width of my chart to)

The problem:

By having a lot of answers the highest result will not have more like: 15%. So my chart isnt nice at all.

The chart of my highest result has to be 100%, the second best result should have some percentage relative on the total.

Is there a way to calculate/fix that ?

Sorry for my english, hope you guys understand.

Comment: cant say I have any idea as to what you mean, sorry.  Can you give us some kind of example?

Comment: Can you please post the code for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a maths question than a coding question I guess, but here it goes.
For the first (highest voted) entry, `$percent` will be `100%`; for the other entries, it's:

```
$percent = $nr_votes * 100 / $first;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your highest result is 100% and all others are relative to it it will not make your chart wider.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do it like this:

```
$answer1 = 20;
$answer2 = 39;
//etc... [probably an array]


$highestAnswer = 39; //You should have some code that generates this
$sizeMultiplier= 100 / $highestAnswer; //This will for example return ~2.5. Multiple all with 2.5 and the highest will be 100.

$answer1Width = $answer1 * $sizeMultiplier;
$answer2Width = $answer2 * $sizeMultiplier;
//etc... [probably an array]
```